# Tutorial question on min number of sample size for confidence interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, bernoulli-distribution

I'm stuck with this question from my tutorial (and there is no worked solution), and I can't seem to get the correct answer of 411.

There were 904 new Subway Restaurants franchises opened during 2002. Suppose that Subway wished to survey a simple random sample of the new franchisees to find out what percentage of them were totally pleased with their relationship with the company. If Subway wanted to have 90% confidence in being within 3 percentage points of the population percentage who are pleased, how many of the new franchisees would have to be included in the sample?

I tried using $p = 0.5$ since the variance is unknown, and $p=0.5$ gives the highest variance. Applying the confidence interval formula, I get:

$ n = 0.5(1-0.5)(\frac{1.6449}{0.03})^2 = 752 $

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on the mistake I have made. Thank you!

Comment: Your formula works well for sampling *with replacement* and you did everything correctly.  But let's reflect on what your answer means.  Do you suppose Subway would be willing to pay for surveying many of its franchisees twice, three times, or more each?  Probably not--so you need instead to apply a formula for sampling *without replacement* (which is what "simple random sample" [usually means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample)).

Comment: @whuber thank you so much for pointing that out! That makes more sense :)

Comment: Also, note that you have a finite population and need to apply a finite population correction. However, I'm not sure that the tutorial was expecting you to do that. I haven't worked out the math to check.

Comment: Correction -- my comment is simply restating what whuber said in a different way and with the correction the math works out.